# How can I access local scope variables in julia custom loggers?

Tags: logging, scope, julia

I want to have a custom logger that will log certain local variables if available. I can’t seem to make the logger see the local variables.
Normally I could do:

```
@info gs_tester
```

to get an output like

```
Info: gs_tester="MYGSTESTERvalue"
```

I however, want to just log like this:

```
function some_worker(gs_tester)
   @info "blahblah"
end
with_logger(logger_that_logs_gs_tester) do
    some_worker(my_gs_tester)
end
```

And I would expect the logging output to be:

```
Info: [MYGSTESTERvalue] blahblah
```

Or, if gs_tester is undeclared:

```
Info: [?] blahblah
```

To this end I have written a logger:

```
logger_that_logs_gs_tester(logger) = TransformerLogger(logger) do log
  try  
      merge(log, (; message = "[$gs_tester] $(log.message)"))
  catch e
      merge(log, (; message = "[?] $(log.message)"))
  end
end
```

However, the gs_tester local variable context is not available. I only get gs_tester if I declare it before the “with_logger” statement which makes this a lot less useful.

How could I go about having a custom logger that will automatically prefix my log message with elements of context if available?

I am making extensive use of LoggingExtras.jl but I’ll settle for a working example in any manner.